# The Brothers Karamazov - ladies of the eighteen stone?

Tags: russian-language, fyodor-dostoyevsky, the-brothers-karamazov

[The Brothers Karamazov by Fyodor Dostoyevsky, Book XI, Chapter IX](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/28054/28054-h/28054-h.html#toc185)

The expression "eighteen stone" is mentioned 3 times in the whole book, all in same chapter:

> What I dream of is becoming incarnate once for all and irrevocably in the form of some merchant's wife weighing **eighteen stone**, and of believing all she believes.

> You are for ever angry, all you care about is intelligence, but I repeat again that I would give away all this super-stellar life, all the ranks and honors, simply to be transformed into the soul of a merchant's wife weighing **eighteen stone** and set candles at God's shrine.

> Well, this wild legend belongs to our middle ages—not yours, but ours—and no one believes it even among us, except the old ladies of **eighteen stone**, not your old ladies I mean, but ours.

What is the relevancy of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The translator chose to "translate" the Russian measure of weight of that time into something that would make sense to English natives.

In the original text Dostoevsky uses the phrase *семипудовая купчиха*, where [*пуд*](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&u=https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%25D0%259F%25D1%2583%25D0%25B4&prev=search&pto=aue) is approx. 16 kilos, while *семь* means "seven".

The narrator ("devil" from Ivan's nightmare) alludes to a stereotypical image of a "merchant's wife" (*купчиха*), usually depicted as.. well, a couple of examples can explain it better:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Was *семипудовая купчиха* a popular/well-known phrase in Russia at that time? Or just something that made sense to describe the stereotype of these ladies?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Tough question as I haven't lived at that time :) As a native speaker, though, I don't see anything special about this phrase - it's just an epithet, and a good one, which might have been coined by Dostoevsky himself on a spur of a moment. It sounds quite natural in Russian, as opposed to "merchant's wife weighing eighteen stone" - which is really awkward and indeed draws one's attention as something weird (especially when repeated several times).